# Unit testing not setting values

Tags: django, unit-testing

I create the user with:

```
self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user('user_1',
                                                     'user_1@test.com',
                                                     'pass')
```

Then I run some form stuff just getting a name and then run a form.submit()

When I try to run:

```
self.assertEqual(self.user.first_name, 'foo')
```

It says '' != 'foo' which means it didn't set the value correctly.

The code itself that I wrote to save it works but for some reason it doesn't set it here in the unit test. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Please show the form, view and test.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run:

```
self.user.refresh_from_db()
```